# Write columns of a data frme directly in rows of an output file without transposing

Tags: r, file, output, transpose

I was wondering how to write columns of a large data frame directly in rows of a text file without transposing the data frame first. Here is an example data frame:

```
a <- c(rep("A1", 3), rep("A2", 3), rep("A3",3))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,2,3,2,6,8)
df <-data.frame(a,b)

df
   a b
1 A1 1
2 A1 1
3 A1 2
4 A2 4
5 A2 2
6 A2 3
7 A3 2
8 A3 6
9 A3 8
```

Here is the output file format I am looking for:

```
A1 1 1 2
A2 4 2 3
A3 2 6 8
```

Thanks very much

Comment: You can open a file connection with `file()` and use `cat()` to write to that file incrementally. It will be painfully slow compared to pivoting your data and using a standard data-frame-writing function.

Comment: Why are you opposing the idea of first reshaping your data?

Comment: I want to avoid transposing the data before writing it in a file as it takes memory/time. Rather than transposing, I thought of just writing it in a transposed form. I have done that with SAS and wondering how to do it in R.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to write in a transposed shape but it was very slow when I tested it on a large data set. It should be useful for a small dataset.

```r
file_conn <- file("out.txt", "w")
k <- 1
for (i in 1:3)
{
  write.table(df$a[k], file_conn, sep = "  ", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " ", quote = FALSE)
  
  for (j in k:(k+2))
  {
    write.table(df$b[j], file_conn, sep = "", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, eol = " ")
  }

  write(' ', file_conn)
  k=k+3
}
close(file_conn)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).